# Unable to figure out query

Tags: sql-server

I have a Table organized as follows:

```
ID  Group
1   I
1   O
1   M
2   I
2   N
2   O
3   M
4   I
5   O
5   M
```

I need to find all IDs are Group M and either group I or O.
In this case group 1 and 5.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use grouping with *conditional aggregates* in `HAVING` clause:

```
SELECT Id 
FROM mytable
WHERE [Group] IN ('I', 'O', 'M') 
GROUP BY Id
HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN [Group] = 'M' THEN 1 END) > 0 AND 
       COUNT(CASE WHEN [Group] IN ('O', 'I') THEN 1 END) > 0
```

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/c7ebf/1)

Comment: Thank you! I'm going to try this with my real example and see if I can get it working.